# The menu disappears when we use Redis with the page cache enabled in Magento 2

Tags: magento-2.3

I am using Magento 2.3 with Redis. The problem was the navigation menu disappears when I enable full page cache. When I disable full page cache, the menu appears.

- full page cache enabled: menu disappears
- full page cache disabled: menu appears

app/etc/env.php

```php
 'cache' => [
        'frontend' => [
            'default' => [
                'backend' => 'Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis',
                'backend_options' => [
                    'server' => '127.0.0.1',
                    'database' => '0',
                    'port' => '6379',
                    'password' => 'xxxx'
                ]
            ],
            'page_cache' => [
                'backend' => 'Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis',
                'backend_options' => [
                    'server' => '127.0.0.1',
                    'database' => '0',
                    'compress_data' => '0',
                    'password' => 'xxxx'
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ],
    'session' => [
            'save' => 'redis',
            'redis' => [
                'host' => '127.0.0.1',
                'database' => '0',
                'port' => '6379',
                'password' => 'xxxx',
            ]
    ],
```

How can I fix this if I want enable full page caché ?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

Go to Stores > Configuration > Advanced > System > Full page cache > Cache application > Choose "Built-in Cache"

**Reason**

The menu doesn't appear if

- you enable "Varnish Cache (Recommended)" instead of "Built-in Cache"
- you don't have Varnish
- and "full page cache" is enabled

Answer (score 0):

I removed the TTL attribute from /vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/layout/default.xml and the menu bar was visible again. Hope it helps someone!